# Show that the order of any power of an element $x$ is a divisor of the order of that element $x$ in $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $x$ be an element of a finite group $G$.  Show that the order of each power of $x$ is a divisor of the order of $x$.

This question is kinda confusing me since isnt this true? $$|<x^{\alpha}>|=|<x>|$$  For all $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}$

If this is true, then of course $|<x^\alpha>|$ divides $|<x>|$, since they're the same, although maybe i'm over looking something and my statement isn't true, can anyone confirm if it's true.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean Lagrange's Theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not true that $|\langle x^a\rangle|=|\langle x\rangle|$ in general. If $a$ is the order of $x$, then $x^a=1$.

However, $|\langle x^a\rangle|$ is a subgroup of $|\langle x\rangle|$, so…

Comment: Ah yes I see why they're not the same now, and then since it's a subgroup then by lagranges theorem it divides it.  Thanks a lot!